# Recharts: allowDuplicatedCategories breaks Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I have a chart that redraws lines based on React state filters. By default, the tooltip appears and works for all points on the line, but once I change the state by selecting a different filter, the tooltip no longer appears. Changing `allowDuplicatedCatories={true}` fixes the issue, but then the tooltip doesn't appear on all points since there are duplicate categories. Is there a workaround to keep this flag as false but show the tooltip on every line without completely restructuring the data format?

Relevant code: Note: `dataKeys` is an array of keys that are generated when the user selects a combination of filters.

```
<ComposedChart data={chartData}>
                <XAxis
                  label={{
                    value: "Date",
                    position: "bottom",
                    dy: 10,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  }}
                  tickFormatter={(tick) => {
                    const parts = tick.split("-");
                    return `${this.tickLabels[parts[1]]}/${parts[2]}`;
                  }}
                  dy={10}
                  dataKey="date"
                  tick={{ fontSize: 12 }}
                  padding={{ left: 20, right: 20 }}
                  interval="preserveStartEnd"
                  allowDuplicatedCategory={false}
                />
                <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
                <Tooltip
                  cursor={{ stroke: "#4c5b5f", strokeWidth: 1 }}
                  formatter={(value) => Math.round(value)}
                />
                {dataKeys.map((key, i) => (
                  <Line
                    name={`${
                      (this.legendLabels[key] || key).split(`|`)[0]
                    }, ${key.split(`|`)[1]} (Mean)`}
                    type="monotone"
                    dataKey={`amt_${key}`}
                    connectNulls
                    dot={false}
                  />
                ))}
              </ComposedChart>
```